# Bind datatrigger style to a property of the content binding objet

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles, datatrigger

I'm trying to do the following. I have a label bound to an object that have two properties. One I want to display and one I want to use for the datatrigger.

Here what's I've come up with yet :

```
 <Label Grid.Row="5" Content="{Binding ElementName=InformationUserControl, Path=Info.ObjectBound}">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Content.InterpretationValue}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <enums:DataInterpretation>Neutral</enums:DataInterpretation>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content.Value}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

The problem is that my Template overrides the default one so it display nothing. Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not that you override the template but that the binding is broken, i would try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Value}" />
```